# I do not understand the use of return *this "as a whole"

Tags: c++

I cannot figure out what the below part of my book I'm reading actually does.

```
//this function supposed to mimic the += operator
Sales_data& Sales_data::combine(const Sales_data &rhs)
{
    units_sold += rhs.units_sold; // add the members of rhs into
    revenue += rhs.revenue;  // the members of ''this'' object
    return *this; // return the object on which the function was called
}

int main()
{
    //...sth sth

    Sales_data total, trans; 
    //assuming both total and trans were also defined...
    total.combine(trans);
    //and here the book says:
    //we do need to use this to access the object as a whole.
    //Here the return statement dereferences this to obtain the object on which the
    //function is executing. That is, for the call above, we return a reference to total.
    //*** what does it mean "we return a reference to total" !?
}
```

I should say that I have previously a little knowledge in C# and don't really understand how exactly `return *this;` affects total object.

Comment: First off, do you understand what "return this" does vs "return *this"?

Comment: Do you understand what a reference is in C++?

Comment: Would you understand a `return this;` written in C#? then in C++ the `return *this` is exactly what `return this` is in C#

Comment: @quetzalcoatl The confusing part is most likely that the return signature of `Sales_data.combine` is a `Sales_data &`.

Comment: It's a good question. Needs more upvotes :)
I struggled with this for the longest time.

Comment: I have no idea what `we do need to use this to access the object as a whole` is supposed to mean. Which book is this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Trivia

The function is returning a reference to a type that's the same as itself, and it returns... itself.

### The pointer type

Because the returned type is a reference type(`Sales_data&`), and `this` is a pointer type(`Sales_data*`), you have to dereference it, thus `*this`, which actually is *the reference to the object we're calling the member function on*.

### Usage

What it really allows is method chaining.

```
Sales_data total;
Sales_data a, b, c, d;

total.combine(a).combine(b).combine(c).combine(d);
```

It's sometimes written vertically:

```
total
    .combine(a)
    .combine(b)
    .combine(c)
    .combine(d);
```

And I am pretty sure you saw it already:

```
cout << "Hello" << ' ' << "World!" << endl;
```

In the above case, overloaded `operator<<` returns a reference to the output stream.

Comment: `thus *this, which actually is the reference to the object we're calling the member function on` Actually, `*this` is an lvalue, and it's not a reference.

Comment: Well, I don't think it is really harmful to think about *this having lvalue ref semantics, but you are probably right.

Comment: I am technically right, but I don't think that this fact requires any more than a footnote.

Answer (score 3):

In the call `total.combine(trans);` the `Sales_data::combine(...)` function is called with `this` as a pointer to `total` and `rhs` as a reference to `trans`. Since `this` is a pointer to total, dereferencing it results in simply the `total` variable.

Then, since the return signature of `Sales_data::combine(...)` is `Sales_data &`, it returns a *reference* to `*this`; in other words, a reference to `total`.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, returning a reference to *this lets you chain function calls like this

```
int main()
{
    Sales_data total, trans; 
    //sth..
    total.combine(trans1).combine(trans2);
    //etc
}
```

By return a reference it means that it returns a reference to the object rather than a copy.  I would imagine that the book you're reading has an explanation of what references are, but it's also available lots of places online.